# Get data on dropdown based on another dropdown value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks, material-ui

Sample API data - http://demo6007276.mockable.io/test

I have three dropdowns as followed:

1. `From Release`
2. `To Release`
3. `Compatability`

Once I select specific `from release` then all `to releases` associated with that `from release` should be available in the `To Release` dropdown which is working. Now I am unable to select a specific `to release` from the `To release` dropdown and it should show its compatibility in the Compatability dropdown. Here is my code:

```
const URL = "http://demo6007276.mockable.io";

export const fetchRelease = async () => {
    try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(`${URL}/test`);
        return data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

```
function HomeFragement() {
    const classes = Styles();

    const [releases, setReleases] = React.useState([]);
    const [fromRelease, setFromRelease] = React.useState('Release1');

    const [toRelease, setToRelease] = React.useState('');
    const [compatability, setCompatability] = React.useState('');

    React.useEffect(() => {
        let unmounted = false;
        const handleFetchReleases = async () => {
            const response = await fetchRelease();
            if (!unmounted) {
                setReleases(response);
            }
        }
        handleFetchReleases();
        return () => {
            unmounted = true;
        };
    }, [])

    let tRelease = releases.filter(item => {
        return item.fromRelease === fromRelease
    })

    let compt = releases.filter(item => {
        return item.fromRelease === fromRelease
    })

    const handleChangeFromRelease = (e) => {
        setFromRelease(e.target.value);
    }

    const handleChangeToRelease = (e) => {
        setToRelease(e.target.value);
    }

    const handleChangeCompatability = (e) => {
        setCompatability(e.target.value);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Box bgcolor="#fff" boxShadow={1} p={2}>
                <form className={classes.root} autoComplete="off">
                    <Grid container spacing={3}>
                        <Grid item xs={3}>
                            <InputLabel>From Release</InputLabel>
                            <Select value={fromRelease} onChange={(e) => handleChangeFromRelease(e)}>
                                {
                                    releases.map((pvalue, i) => {
                                        return <MenuItem key={i} value={pvalue.fromRelease}> {pvalue.fromRelease} </MenuItem>
                                    })
                                }
                            </Select>
                        </Grid>

                        <Grid item xs={3}>
                            <InputLabel>To Release</InputLabel>
                            <Select value={toRelease} onChange={(e) => handleChangeToRelease(e)}>
                                {
                                    tRelease[0] && tRelease[0].releases.map((pvalue, i) => {
                                        return <MenuItem key={i} value={pvalue.toRelease}> {pvalue.toRelease} </MenuItem>
                                    })
                                }
                            </Select>
                        </Grid>

                        <Grid item xs={3}>
                            <InputLabel>Compatability</InputLabel>
                            <Select value={compatability} onChange={(e) => handleChangeCompatability(e)}>
                                {
                                    compt[0] && compt[0].releases.map((pvalue, i) => {
                                        return <MenuItem key={i} value={pvalue.compatability}> {pvalue.compatability} </MenuItem>
                                    })
                                }
                            </Select>
                        </Grid>                     
                    </Grid>
                </form>
            </Box>
        </div>
    )
}
export default HomeFragement
```

Any suggestion, please?

Comment: Can you host this on codesandbox?

Comment: @PrathameshKoshti check https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-cache-4q4pk?file=/src/HomeFragement.js

Comment: There are so many errors in your code. Can you try resolving those issues! I'm not able to see UI because of errors

Comment: From api I'm getting undefined as a response, because of which filter method is failing

Comment: @PrathameshKoshti yes I just checked. However It is working in visual studio code. Can you tell why it is happening? Here is api path http://demo6007276.mockable.io/test

Comment: I was able to run it in my local system. Can you tell me on thing? WHen I select one option from "To Release", then what should be displayed in the third dropdown? Compatibility which is related to the release? RIght? So do you really need that second option? You can just show readonly textfield for compatibility where you can show the text according to the "To release" option

Comment: @PrathameshKoshti yes you are right. I need to display compatibility related to "toRelease". You can do it in text field in this case we do not need the third dropdown. I had kept it considering other things. By the way thanks for taking your time and setting up things on ur system. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks once again!!

Comment: Okay will take a look at it

Comment: @PrathameshKoshti can you please check https://codesandbox.io/s/github/abiodunsulaiman694/excel-app/tree/master/ Unable to add multiple rows properly in it. Any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: Can you create a new question and please add some description in it

Comment: @PrathameshKoshti here is link to the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65494848/unable-to-add-rows-properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made few changes in your code. I created new state for compatibilities array which will hold compatibilities based on the selected toRelease (Even though right now you are getting only one compatibility, in future you may receive many, so better to have an array).

`const [compatibilities, setCompatabilities] = React.useState([]);`

Then modified below method:

```js
const handleChangeToRelease = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    setToRelease(value);
    // first get the selected fromRelease
    const fromReleaseObj = releases.find(release => release.fromRelease === fromRelease);
    // by using fromRelease object get the selected toRelease object
    const toReleaseObj = fromReleaseObj.releases.find(release => release.toRelease === value);
    // now set the array we defined earlier using react hook to `toReleaseObj`'s compatibility
    setCompatibilities([toReleaseObj.compatability])
};
```

In your render method, make sure you are using the compatibilities array which was defined earlier in this answer.

```js
<Grid item xs={3}>
  <InputLabel>Compatability</InputLabel>
    <Select
      value={compatability}
      onChange={(e) => handleChangeCompatability(e)}
    >
      {compatibilities.map((compatability, i) => {
        return (
        <MenuItem key={i} value={compatability}>
          {" "}
          {compatability}{" "}
        </MenuItem>
      );
    })}
  </Select>
</Grid>
```

Here's the code sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-bird-bme2u, It won't work because you might get some CORS error and in console you may see `Failed to fetch`. So make sure you export it using file menu and download it in your system.

Once downloaded, using terminal install npm packages using the command `npm run install` and run it using `npm start`.