# unable to add rows properly

Tags: reactjs, antd

**Unable to add multiple rows properly**. Follow below steps:

1. Click on sample excel sheet to download it.
2. Once same sheet is imported all data is shown.
3. Column values can be updated by clicking on its value and changing it.

However When I add more rows, it appears twice and unable to change its column value by clicking on it.

Even after adding rows to it. There is no key attached to that row as shown below:

**Before adding rows:**

[image]

**After adding rows:**

[image]

`Codesandbox link:` https://codesandbox.io/s/github/abiodunsulaiman694/excel-app/tree/master/

Comment: It's not a good idea to use index as key  see this part of react [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys) or this [source](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318)

Comment: @antoineso can you help me with the code link that i have put in question. I am new to react.

Comment: You try to render inside `this.state = {}` why is that?

Comment: [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/still-paper-dg3x6?file=/package.json)

Comment: @antoineso thanks for helping. It worked. Can you please quicky explain what did you change exactly. I can see u used nanoid for key. Is there anything else did you use?

Comment: sure I'll post an answer as soon as possible

Comment: @Nitin, you deleted a question about [printing a pyramid from characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67043354/character-pyramind-in-java), a possible implementation using a `StringBuilder` and its `reverse` method is shown [here](https://ideone.com/oxZ2LT)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of index and if your object array don't have unique value (like id) you can use the [nanoid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nanoid) package and then in your map function do something like this in Excelenderer function :

```
  ExcelRenderer(fileObj, (err, resp) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        let newRows = [];
        resp.rows.slice(1).map((row) => {
          if (row && row !== "undefined") {
            newRows.push({
              key: nanoid(),
              name: row[0],
              age: row[1],
              gender: row[2]
            });
          }
        });
```

and in handleAdd function:

```
 handleAdd = () => {
    const { count, rows } = this.state;
    const newData = {
      key: nanoid(),
      name: "User's name",
      age: "22",
      gender: "Female"
    };
    this.setState({
      rows: [newData, ...rows],
      count: count + 1
    });
  };
```

it will generate an unique key by calling `nanoid()` from nanoid library.
**carefull**
don't use nanoid in render function 
like explain in nanoid doc :

> Do not call nanoid in the key prop. In React, key should be consistent
> among renders.
>
> This is the bad example:
>
> /* DON’T DO IT */

here [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/still-paper-dg3x6?file=/package.json)